# C# OleDbConnection.Open causes a buffer overrun

Tags: c#, memory, oledbconnection

I have this `OleDbConnection` which is trying to open a connection using the `OleDbConnection.Open()` method but it throws me the exception:

> Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory

Does anybody know what causes this or how can it be fixed?

Comment: It doesn't need to be a buffer overrun. A GPF/NPE is equally possible. Also, you need to specify what OleDb provider is involved, preferrably with the initialization code.

Comment: Null pointer exception, general protection fault

Comment: Which OleDb provider is it ? Could you provide the connection string used ?

Comment: "MyDbProvider.myProvider.1;Server=192.168.0.23;Port=1117;TimeStamp=634381361089557500;"

Comment: The TimeStamp sure look weird.  And, it has a soft-hypen character in the string:  TimeStamp=6343813610895&shy;57500;

Comment: It look like a custom OleDb provider you develop, or a exotic one from a third party. Do you have some additional info ?